# Golang Вывод новостей на сайт в обратном порядке из массива

Tags: golang, сортировка

Прошу направить в нужное направление) Недавно начал изучать go, столкнулся с такой проблемой как вывод новостей в web в обратном порядке, как лучше это реализовать?
Тут я делаю запрос к БД и передаю в структурный массив.

```
func index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    t, err := template.ParseFiles("templates/index.html", "templates/header.html", "templates/footer.html")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, err.Error())
    }
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:root@tcp(127.0.0.1:8889)/golang")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()
    res, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM articles")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    posts = []Article{}

    for res.Next() {
        var post Article
        err = res.Scan(&post.Id, &post.Title, &post.Anons, &post.Text)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        posts = append(posts, post)
        fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("кол-во постов %d", len(posts)))
        //fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("ID: %d title: %s anonse: %s text %s", post.Id, post.Title, post.Anons, post.Text))
    }
    t.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index", posts)
}
```

Тут моя html страница на которой приохотит вывод данных

```
  {{define "index"}}
{{template "header"}}

    <main role="main" class="inner cover">
        <h1 class="cover-heading">Главная страница теста Goland</h1>
        <p class="lead"></p>
{{ range . }}
    <div class="aler alert-danger">
        <h2>{{.Title}}</h2>
        <p>{{ .Anons}}</p>
        <a href="/post/{{ .Id }}" class="btn btn-danger">Читать статью</a>
    </div>

    {{end}}
 
    <br>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary">Узнать больше!</a>
        </p>
    </main>
{{template "footer"}}
{{end}}
```

Собственно текущий скриншот. Видно что новости которая должна быть первой отображается последней.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: когда вы прочитали все элементы в posts, то разверните этот массив. либо отсортируйте уже в SQL `SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY id DESC `

Comment: Да спасибо Вам огромное! Я и совсем забыл что SQL запросом можно сортировать. И по первому варианту с разворотом массива тоже все получилось)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

когда вы прочитали все элементы в `posts`, то разверните этот массив. либо отсортируйте уже в `SQL SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY id DESC`